# Vim color schemes don't load anymore

Tags: vim, macports, color-scheme

Today I installed the last version of MacPorts on my laptop, since then (though I cannot be sure that this is the real cause) vim's color schemes don't load anymore. Instead, a strange black-and-white color scheme shows up, in which line numbers and reserved keywords are underlined.

[image: (That's what I am talking 'bout)]

If I try to change color scheme the syntax highlighting changes a bit, but still black and white.

**Note** that MacVim, which shares `.vimrc` with text-based vim, display the correct color scheme.

**I have already tried** relaxing file permissions on the `colors` and `syntax` directories in the vim directory.

Do you have any idea on what could have happened?

Thank you
Tunnuz

Comment: What is the output of `:set runtimepath?`? In Terminal.app, what is the output of `$ echo $TERM`? Did you install Vim through MacPorts? Does the problem persist when launching Vim without any plugin/.vimrc?

Comment: `:set runtimepath outputs `runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vi
m/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after`, the output of `echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color`. I did not reinstall vim through MacPorts and the problems persists even when launching without any `.vimrc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like an issue with vim's ability to detect if your terminal supports colors. Take a look at [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_06.html#06.2) from the vim documentation, specifically the second bullet point.

Comment: Actually, setting TERM to xterm-color *does* make vim behave correctly, but other applications (man) to output warnings about the terminal functionality. Is there a way to make vim recognize that xterm-256color *is* a color terminal?

Comment: I see from your picture that you are running Lion, this means that Terminal.app does support 256 colors, so you should leave TERM along (aka: xterm-256color). There is probably a better fix, but as a work around try adding the lines mentioned here to your .vimrc. http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#xterm-color

Comment: I do have Lion. However, even if I leave TERM as xterm-256color, vim doesn't recognize this is a color terminal.

Comment: Understoon which is why I suggested in my last comment that you use the process suggested by the link (adding that block of text to your `.vimrc`). This way you can leave TERM the way it is and force vim to have colors. Also, the 'better fix' that I mentioned might involve getting 'terminfo' data for xterm-256color and adding it to your system. I don't know too much about it but it might be something to research.